# Is there a way to sign in Power Bi with code?

Tags: powerbi

Power Bi now has a new option to share a Dashboard with someone. It is called "incorporate" or something like that (that is the word in Portuguese; I don't know if it is a different word in English).

It is a good way to share because you can incorporate it in your web site. It needs you to sign in to see the dashboard (which provides much more security than the "publish in web" option).

But, if I have a site with a sign-in, is there a way that I can sign in Power Bi via API or something like that?

If I create a portal to embed the Power Bi's Dashboard, the final client will need to sign twice, and I don't think that's is a good idea.

And I'm not using the Power Embedded Service, just the Power Bi Service (Pro license).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate service account (with Pro license) that sign-in to Power BI automatically from the portal. By this way, the final client will just have to sign-in once into the portal without signing in separately for Power BI again.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. But how can I do it programatically? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I am not a front end person @MatheusRocha. But you can search in this direction depending on the front end technology you are using for your portal. 

I was just trying to give you some direction as that's what our front end team did in my last project (they were using Drupal front end integration)